# GRASS r.stats.zonal help

Tags: grass-gis, integer

I am following this tutorial but redoing it with more current data:
https://ecodiv.earth/TutorialsNotes/deerdensities/results.html

I am recieving the error: `ERROR: The base map must be an integer (CELL) map` when I get to the portion of the code that says: `r.stats.zonal base=dpa cover=HSI_deer method=average output=HSI_average`

I am not doing this in python as the user is but just in the console in GRASS.

Here is what I have so far and I am getting stuck on line 17.When I look at my data list I do not see the dpa [image]

He describes this step that it calculates the average suitability scores per DPA (Deer Permit Area) but I am pretty new to this so I am not sure how to fix this error even though I feel like I understand what he wants to do. Here is a link where he discusses this section further:
https://ecodiv.earth/TutorialsNotes/deerdensities/spatialallocation.html. All this data he provides if youd like to replicate with the older data.

```
1.  r.in.gdal -e input="C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/NLCD_2019_Land_Cover.tif" output=NLCD_2019

2.  v.in.ogr -e input="C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/bdry_state_of_minnesota.gpkg" output=Minnesota_boundary

3.  g.region -a raster=NLCD_2019 vector=Minnesota_boundary
4.  r.mask vector = "Minnesota_boundary"

5.  r.recode.attr input="NLCD_2019" output="DHSI"  rules="C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/deerSHI.csv"

6.  r.mask -i raster="NLCD_2019" maskcats='11 23 24' overwrite=True

7.  r.mfilter input=DHSI_shelter output=DHSI_shelters filter="C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/QHFwaf.txt"

8.  r.mfilter input=DHSI_food output=DHSI_foods filter="C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/QHFwaf.txt"

9.  r.series input=DHSI_Shelters,DHSI_Foods output=HSI_deer method=minimum

10. r.mask vector="Minnesota_boundary" overwrite=True 

11. r.null map="HSI_deer" null=0

12. v.in.ogr --overwrite input=C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/bdry_deer_permit_areas.gpkg output=deer_den

13. db.in.ogr --overwrite input=C:/Users/Megan/Desktop/Test/DPA_deer_densities19.csv output=deerden 

14. v.db.join map=deer_den column=DPA other_table=deerden other_column=DPA

15. v.to.rast input=deer_den@Megan_updated where=density2019 !='' output=deer_temp use=attr attribute_column=density2019

16. r.grow.distance input=deer_temp value=deer_den

17. r.stats.zonal base=dpa cover=HSI_deer method=average output=HSI_average
```

Comment: Did you consider to contact the author at https://ecodiv.earth/#contact ?

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot of the list of available maps, you already have the MN deer permit areas as a vector. (I see that the DPA boundaries are available from [the MN geospatial website](https://gisdata.mn.gov/dataset/bdry-deer-permit-areas)). I would convert that polygon vector to a raster with `v.to.rast` using the DPA column for raster values, and call the output `dpa`.  Then retry step 17 with the `basemap=` parameter pointing to this new `dpa` raster.